# Loop random numbers for a switch case up to n times

Tags: javascript, loops, random, switch-statement

i´m getting crazy with this...I need to loop 10 times (automaticaly) a random number between 1-4 (both included), and this numbers must obtain a colour from switch cases', printed in the console.I tried to separate the switch cases, random function & the loop of that random function but....Any suggest???

```
//colours to assiged(depending on random number)
function getColor(colorNumber=0)
{
   colorNumber = parseInt(colorNumber);
   switch(colorNumber){
       case 1: return "red"; 
               break;
       case 2: return "yellow"; 
               break;
       case 3: return "blue"; 
               break;
       case 4: return "green"; 
               break;
       default: return "black"; 
                break;
   }
}
//var with random generated
function getAllStudentColors(){
   var getAllStudentColors = Math.floor(Math.random(4-1)*10) + 1;
   }
//looping for function of random numbers
function loop() {    
var exampleColor = 0;
   while (exampleColor = 1) {
       getAllStudentColors();
       exampleColor++;
   }
}
var exampleColor = getColor();
getAllStudentColors();
```

Comment: You generate a random number and do not use it. You call the function that wants the number, but you do not pass it a number.....

Comment: Note that `Math.random` doesn't take any arguments. It always returns a floating point number between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a loop function with paramters for the count of loops and the function which should be called for every iteration and collect the result in an array.

I simplified the `getColor` fuunction by using an array and a fefault value for handing over an unknown property.

```js
//colours to assiged(depending on random number)
function getColor(colorNumber = 0) {
    return ["black", "red", "yellow", "blue", "green"][colorNumber] || "black";
}

//var with random generated
function getRandomColor() {
    return getColor(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5));
}

//looping for function of random numbers
function loop(n, fn) {
    let colors = [];

    while (n--) colors.push(fn());

    return colors;
}

console.log(...loop(10, getRandomColor));
```